# Linux chcon: can't apply partial (Fedora 22)

Tags: linux, permissions, fedora

I try to change permission over `MYAPP` dir  because it  has **777** permissions because SEliux has blocked it

So I type this command

`su -c "chcon -R -h -t httpd_sys_script_rw_t /usr/share/nginx/html/MYAPP/`

but i getting this error

```
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file HtmlPhpSpecExceptionPresenter.php
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file Exception
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file StringPresenter.php
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file TaggingPresenter.php
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file Presenter.php
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file SimplePresenter.php
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file PresenterInterface.php
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file Presenter
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file FatalPresenter.php
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file HtmlFormatter.php
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file ReportFailedItem.php
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file ReportSkipped.html
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file ReportFooter.html
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file ReportPending.html
```

**Note: this happen on `remote server` but on my `local machine` worked well**

Answer (score 1):

Check with semanage command.

`semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_script_rw_t "/usr/share/nginx/html/MYAPP(/.*)?"`

`restorecon -R -v MYAPP`

First check with some demo folder.